# Is there a hook similar to "save_post" which only fires AFTER the post is completely published?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, posts, hooks

I am writing a plugin that involves fetching multiple images from an external server, uploading them into the Wordpress media gallery, then attaching them to a custom post type (Woocommerce product).

I set this up to occur only when a new product is published.

Using "save_post" does indeed work, but it seems that it runs WHILE the post is in saving/publishing state (page loading), so the actual "publishing" of the post can take up to 30-40 seconds depending on how many images there are.

I want this functionality to happen AFTER the post is fully published, so that when I click "publish" in the WP admin dashboard, it isn't stuck in a loading state for 30-40 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `post_updated` hook?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried both post_updated and even found out about "wp_after_insert_post", but they both seem to run while the product is saving/publishing. I am only guessing this due to the 30+ second timeline for it to save. May just have to work with this.

Comment: Strange, post_updated hook fires after the database was updated. Just try to imagine why you decided to 'trigger' image upload on a post save. Isn't it better to upload images first, just then allow to save post.

Comment: Very good idea, I personally think uploading all the images then attaching the id's to their respective post as they are uploaded makes sense. My original method is unfortunately a requirement, but I will see if this way is acceptable instead. Thank you.